# Two buttons needed at navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem. Image not getting displayed

Tags: iphone

I have to have two buttons on the right side of the navigation bar. So i created a tool bar and added two bar button items to its content view. Like below.

```
UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"share-icon-32x32.png"]
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self action:@selector(showShare)];

    shareButton.width = 30.0f;
    [buttons addObject:shareButton];
    [shareButton release];
```

where buttons is an array holding the button objects.

Like wise i have another barbutton item like below

```
UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                      initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                                      target:self
                                      action:@selector(addDescription)];

        addButton.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
        [buttons addObject:addButton];
        [addButton release];
```

Now add the array to the toolbar like below

```
[toolbar setItems:buttons animated:YES];
    [buttons release];
```

and add it to the rightBarButton like below

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                              initWithCustomView:toolbar];
    [toolbar release];
```

I am getting two bar button items on the right bar but i am not able to get the image displayed on to the share button item. Its just a white patch. Can any body tell me what am i doing wrong or how to get the image displayed.

Regards,

Syed Yusuf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs for `initWithImage:style:target:action:`:

> The alpha values in the source image are used to create the images—opaque values are 
>   ignored.

This means that UIKit uses the alpha channel of your image, not the RGB pixel values. The image you provided is probably completely opaque (has no transparency) and initWithImage:style:target:action: interprets this as a white square. You must save your image with an alpha channel that defines the shape of your icon.

Comment: Hi Begemann,

Thanks a lot. Yes i was using an opaque image. I used an equivalent gray-scaled image and it did show up in the nav bar.

Regards,
Syed Yusuf